# Can't convert curve to points if the curve has a bevel in the Geometry panel

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

As per title, whenever working with **Geometry Nodes** and **curves** I can never convert a curve to points or resample it (or do any kind of procedure involving curve functions to it) if the curve has a bevel applied to it in the curve data properties (or mesh modifiers for that matter, such as subdivision surface or similar), under the Geometry panel. I understand this, since what is probably happening is that the Geometry Nodes modifier is interpreting the curve as a mesh once there is some bevel to it.

However, I believe there must be some way to access the curve data in the Geometry Nodes even if there are modifiers or other things done to the curve before the Geometry Nodes modifier.

Might a script work for this matter? Is there anything I can do directly in the Geometry Nodes setup for the curve? Thank you.

Comment: just a dumb question: why don't you bevel your curve with GN? just two nodes to do that ‍♂️

Comment: ... same question as @Chris ..you could even make a separate 'Bevel Curve' GN group with all the features in the data panel, and more, stashing the original curve data, further up the stack.

Comment: @Chris I honestly had no idea you could do that ahaha, looked around a bit and managed it. Looking for it online didn't help, nor did the fact that this function, which in one part of the program is called "bevel" on another part of the program is called "curve to mesh". There is a bit of inconsistency for nomenclature in Blender to be honest. I always thought the curve to mesh node simply converts the curve into mesh segments without anything else, so I didn't bother testing it.